# Authentication between Windows and Linux servers on two hosts but same domain - possible?

Tags: sql, mysql, windows, linux, authentication

We have an issue that I can't wrap my head around regarding possible solutions.

We have a site that runs off of a Dot Net Nuke CMS, with a custom asp.net CMS powering a reviews engine aspect of it too.  This is hosted on a Windows server setup on SQL servers and has its own user registry.

We are looking at a script for an add on revenue offering, and the best of breed we have found happens to be Linux-based using MySQL servers.  There are some other options, but none are nearly as robust as the Linux based one.

Our quandry is two-fold:

1) If we use this script, we will need to host a linux server with a different host service (ours only does windows servers).   Both server sets will point to the same domain (www.mydomain.com) and have communication between the MySQL DB on the Linux machine and the SQL DB on the Windows machine.

- Is this possible...and problematic?  Or is this a fairly straightforward issue to solve?

2) The larger issue if the first is a hurdle that can be cleared is we would want to share our user registry between the two databases, so the user would not be logging into each DB when going between the two environments.

This issue is more complex than my understanding of authentication and databases so I'm hoping someone can help me out or at least start me in a good direction for research.

We could go with the other script routes, but they simply don't offer the functions or features of the more difficult to implement code.

Comment: This is really a question for your hosting service. Also you may find http://serverfault.com/ useful. I suspect that the answer is "no you can't do that", probably for firewalling reasons, but I could be entirely wrong.

Comment: Script could me a lot of things. What is the technology of this script?

Comment: Conrad, it is a groupon clone.  Developed with PHP, MySQL, Linux, Apache and CakePHP Framework.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you can always run MySQL on the Windows box and install cgywin to run the script in a more unix type environment. Or run xampp on a different port: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: Wouldn't there be security issues in both cgywin (as it wouldn't run the program fully) and xampp on a public server?

Comment: There are security issues with running any server. As I didn't read your follow previously, I think the XAMPP setup is probably better as it has PHP and MySQL and Apache, and you can install the Cake Framework. The same security problems with running such a setup exist in Linux. I run a very similar production server using Linux and still run into security problems especially with PHP.